# how to signed json file using e pass signature in postman

Tags: sql, json, api, sdk, postman

I am trying  to send file  using postman API collection and it work good but after I send file I have error
(" ITIDA Signature Invalid Signature • ISFX306 Document Signature Error : Invalid Signature Format. • 4040 4040:Invalid digital signature format[IOException reading content.]")
so I trying to signed JSOn file from USB token (e pass 2003) on postman but I didn't know how to configure it postman

[image: 1]

I am trying configure e pass token on postman

Answer (score 0):

The Postman itself well NOT sign JSON documents using the e-pass2003 or others, but you may use the "pre-request scripts" feature to serialize and sign documents using your own JavaScript code.

Kindly refer to the following link to get more information about that feature in Postman:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/